# How to align image right in lightbox when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am trying to align the image to the right when clicked.  I have a lightbox script but cannot figure out how to move the image from the center to the right.

Here is the script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
<style type="text/css">
a.fancybox img {
    border: none;
    -o-transform: scale(1,1); 
    -ms-transform: scale(1,1); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); 
    transform: scale(1,1); 
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
} 
a.fancybox:hover img {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 999; -o-transform: 
    scale(1.03,1.03); 
    -ms-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); 
    transform: scale(1.03,1.03);
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($){
        var addToAll = true;
        var gallery = true;
        var titlePosition = 'inside';
        $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var title = $this.attr('title');
            var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
            var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
            $this.wrap(a);
        });
        if (gallery)
            $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
            titlePosition: titlePosition
        });
    });
    $.noConflict();
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also, if there is a way to make the lightbox cover the whole page, that would be cool too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you update your html markup.

Comment: Updated html as requested!

Comment: It is better to give an online demo instead of pasting your html page.

Comment: The lightbox doesn't cover the navigation section... is there a way to get it to cover the nav section?

Comment: @Michael, add float:right to this class a.fancybox img, and check

Comment: No luck. Still not right justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below in `css`

```
#fancybox-wrap{
    left:auto !important;
    right:0 !important;
}
```

```js
$(function($) {
  var addToAll = true;
  var gallery = true;
  var titlePosition = 'inside';
  $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var title = $this.attr('title');
    var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
    var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
    $this.wrap(a);
  });
  if (gallery)
    $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
  $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
    titlePosition: titlePosition
  });
});
```

```css
    a.fancybox img {
      border: none;
      -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
      -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
      transform: scale(1, 1);
      -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    a.fancybox:hover img {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 999;
      -o-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
      transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    }
    #fancybox-wrap {
      left: auto !important;
      right: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
<section class="main clearfix">
  <section class="top">
    <div class="wrapper content_header clearfix">
      <div class="work_nav">
        <h1 class="title">Map Gallery</h1>
      </div>
  </section>
  <!-- end top -->

  <section class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <p align="center">Click to enlarge any map.</p>
      <ul id="movieposters">
        <li>
          <img class="fancybox" src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-45891755,width-640,resizemode-4/nasas-images-of-most-remarkable-events-you-cant-miss.jpg" width=200px height=200px />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="fancybox" src="https://risehighershinebrighter.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/magic-of-blue-universe-images.jpg" width=200px height=200px />
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
  </section>
</section>
<!-- end main -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You, my friend, are an absolute genious!

Comment: Glad Michael, now move your bicycle :).

Comment: Rohan, may I ask one more question?

Is there a way to only have the images within the <ul> to expand in the lightbox?  I noticed that any image on the page is clickable and goes into a lightbox zoom when clicked.  For example, my logo is in the nav bar, and when click it is supposed to go to the home page, however, because the fancybox is referencing all images, when you click the logo, it goes into a lightbox zoom.  Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Yes make your addtoall variable to false like `var addToAll = false;` or just use `$('img.fancybox').each(function(){` instead of `$(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){`

Comment: Wow! Again, absolute genius. You made my night! Thank you <3!